# Patch in SpringDataJPA

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-data-jpa, retrofit

I am writing a mobile application in Android. I have a TomCat server, use SpringBoot and SpringData JPA. To connect Android to server, I use Retrofit. I'm a rookie at it so could you help me please how to update the database with the use of Patch? I have a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student") 
public class StudentController {
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@Autowired
public StudentController(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
}



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH)//dodanie
public String updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
{
   studentRepository.save(student);
    return "{success:true}";
}

//zwraca liste studentow
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Student> getStudent(){
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

JPA repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{

}
```

And from Android:

```
public interface StudentClient {
@PATCH("student")

Call<Student>updateStudent(@Body Student student);
 }
```

Is there anything missing? Should I add something anywhere or to the JPA?

Comment: We wouldn't know if anything is missing. You tell us. Do you have any errors? Anything not working as you'd expect?

Comment: Why do you want to use PATCH, for add/update you should use `POST/PUT`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic.

You can refer this tutorial to understand, perhaps, how PATCH verb could be implemented at server side.

http://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring

And this tutorial for UI side.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-update-objects-on-the-server-put-vs-patch